# How can I convert between EU, MJ, and Blutricity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have RedPower, BuildCraft and Thermal Expansion, and IndustrialCraft. Unfortunately, these all use different forms of energy. Is there a way to convert between the three forms of energy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, but not directly (unless you're using the Ultimate or YogCraft pack.)

In the **Direwolf20** and **Mindcrack** packs, you can easily convert EU to MJ and BC to MJ using the Electrical Engine and the Blulectric Engine respectively. You can convert MJ to EU by using engines (of any sort) connected to a Magma Crucible, which is fed by either cobblestone or netherrack. This produces lava, which can be pumped into a geothermal generator to produce EU. Unfortunately, there is still no way to convert to Blutricity, although the developer of Redpower says it will come in a future update.

In the **Ultimate** and **YogCraft** pack there are Power Converters. This allows much easier conversion. The above trick using the Magma Crucible still works.

Comment: Also, there is a blulectric engine, which can convert blutricity into MJs. As for creating blutricity, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what pack you're using.

- In the **Direwolf20** and **Mindcrack** FTB packs, not really, no. The Electrical Engine is powered by EU and outputs MJ, but the reverse isn't possible. RedPower2's own Blutricity Engine also generates MJ, but nothing converts *to* Blutricity.
- In **FTB Ultimate** you have the [Power Converters](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1629898-147-powercrystals-mods-mfr-23-powerconverters-netherores-and-more/#pc-desc) mod available. It provides a set of blocks that can be configured to convert between EU, MJ, Volts/Amps/Watts (Universal Electricity), Steam, and Charge (Factorization). There is still no way to convert to Blutricity, however.

Comment: Darn. That kind of sucks

Comment: You can convert from blutricity to MJ by using a blulectric engine, but there is no way to convert anything other power to blutricity

Comment: @Steve That's right! I forgot about those.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to convert RF/MI into EU in FTB DIREWOLF20

If you charge power armor in the energetic infuser and discharge it in a MFSU. You can automate it with tesseracts/BC pipes/Itemducts